# Expected Value and Summation

Tags: probability

The question is suppose $X$ ~ $Geometric(\frac{1}{2})$ and I have computed $P(X > 1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $Var(X) = 2$ where $E[X] = 2$ and $E[X^2] = 6$. How can I verify that $E[X] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X > n)$. I know that this formula holds in general but which theorem relates all of these for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\Pr(X\gt n)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$. Add up, $0$ to $\infty$.

Why is $\Pr(X\gt n)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$? We have $X\gt n$ if and only if we start with $n$ consecutive "failures."

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n=[X\gt n]$. Then $E[X]=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}P[A_n]$ because $X=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}\mathbf 1_{A_n}$.

For example, if $X(\omega)=3$, the sequence $(\mathbf 1_{A_n}(\omega))_{n\geqslant0}$ starts with $1,1,1,0,0,\ldots$